# Linking to native Google Play store app from browser

Tags: android, google-play

I want to link to Google Play/Marketplace app from a webpage in the same manner I do for the iPhone "itms://itunes.apple.com/...". Is this possible for the Android device to open Google Play/Market place native app with my app vs the webpage?

Comment: Try this which I found on google: `market://details?id=your.identifier`

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to worry about all this stuff. Just create a link pointing to `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your.package.name`. You don't have to use any alternative protocol.

Depending on the users' settings they'll be asked which app they'd like to use to view the URL (if there's more than one). By default this will open the store page using Google Play.

Advantage over using any custom URL parsing or anything would be the fact that desktop users are still able to use the URL and install (or buy) the app using the web version of the market.

Comment: Cheers Mario. This works when the user clicks on it (as a standard href) but not when I want to do it in JavaScript as a redirect to it using "window.location.href". Any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: Might be a security feature to avoid web pages remote controlling any apps (there's been a recent discovery of a similar vulnerability with the Steam client and its protocol/URLs). Have you had a look at the JS triggering similar things, e.g. forums supporting Tapatalk? I think those open in the store (after you click on a message box).

Answer (score -1):

Not 100% clear on if you want to launch this from a browser or from within your code, but from within Android, you simply use "Intent" - here's an example of how to launch it:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle(R.string.unlicensed_dialog_title)
    .setMessage(R.string.unlicensed_dialog_body)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.buy_button,
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
        int which) {
            Intent marketIntent = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("http://market.android.com/details?id=com.myappname"));
            startActivity(marketIntent);
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton(R.string.quit_button,
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
        int which) {
            finish();
        }
    }).create();
}
```

This would show a Dialog with the option to go to the Google Play store.

This is the part that actually does the work:

```
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(
Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("http://market.android.com/details?id=com.myappname"));
startActivity(marketIntent);
```

Comment: He wants do it from "*from a webpage*", and his title says "*from browser*".

Comment: True, but he also says: "open Google Play/Market place native app **with my app** _vs_ the webpage" Which is why I said it wasn't clear if he wanted to do it **from** his app, which case coding it is the way to go. :-)