# how to open an application from browser on android

Tags: android

I want to call android application on clicking of button or image on some website from mobile. Suppose I am opening one image or url on android browser and I want to call another application on clicking on button provided by that site. How to do that??

I am blogger and i want to open play store application from browser when my readers click on Google Play Badges image.

Comment: If you just want to open the Play Store app, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131676/linking-to-native-google-play-store-app-from-browser

Comment: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to start an application from WebView:
[Android SDK WebView call Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846296/android-sdk-webview-call-activity)
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript

**But it is not possible to send intent from regular web browser.**

Edit:

If you need to open Google Play just use a regular html a href with the url of an application on the Google Play.

P.S. : Take a look on this useful thread [Make a link in the Android browser start up my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469908/make-a-link-in-the-android-browser-start-up-my-app)

Comment: This applies only to `WebView`s within an app, not a regular browser.